# Check if one row exists in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, row

I have two tables:

**friends:**

```
accountId | friendId
--------------------
       A1 |      B15
       A1 |      C34
       A1 |      D48
```

and **followers**

```
accountId | followerId
----------------------
       A1 |        B15
       A1 |        C34
```

I try to run a MYSQL query that will return a "friendId" that does not exist in "followerId" column in the other table. Basically i try to find, which rows from the "friends" table, do not exist in the "followers" table.

I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM friends AS f
LEFT JOIN followers AS l
ON f.accountId = l.accountId
WHERE l.accountId IS NULL
```

but it return nothing. No result. Just null. I have checked the validity of the tables manually, and it does actually contain such entries. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM friends AS f
LEFT JOIN followers AS l
  ON f.accountId = l.accountId
 AND f.friend_id = l.follower_id   -- additional condition
WHERE l.accountId IS NULL;
```

Output:

```
accountId | friendId | accountId | follower_id
       A1 |      D48 | NULL      | NULL
```

Comment: Damn. This worked. Thank you. I will approve your answer in 10 minutes.